# Using PHP Gender extension in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I've got the Gender guessing extension of php working on my localhost.
http://php.net/manual/en/gender.example.admin.php

Following the instructions in a non-cakephp project all I have to do is:

```
namespace Gender;
$gender = new Gender;
$name = "Milene";
$country = Gender::FRANCE;

$result = $gender->get($name, $country);
$data = $gender->country($country);
```

And that produces the correct results. However if I put the above code in a function in cakephp I get an error:

```
syntax error, unexpected 'Gender' (T_STRING), expecting \\ (T_NS_SEPARATOR)
```

I think it's something to do with using namespaces but I'm not really sure how that all works (Have been and will continue to google). Can anyone shed any light on how I can use this Gender extension in cakephp?

**EDIT**
Here is the error logs:

```
Stack Trace:
#0 [internal function]: OwnerAccountsController->dashboard()
#1 /var/www/html/rrv3/lib/Cake/Controller/Controller.php(491): ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(Object(OwnerAccountsController), Array)
#2 /var/www/html/rrv3/lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php(193): Controller->invokeAction(Object(CakeRequest))
#3 /var/www/html/rrv3/lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php(167): Dispatcher->_invoke(Object(OwnerAccountsController), Object(CakeRequest))
#4 /var/www/html/rrv3/app/webroot/index.php(110): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#5 {main}
```

**And this** is the exact code I'm using in my dashboard function:

```
$gender = new \Gender\Gender();
$name = "Milene";
$country = \Gender\Gender::FRANCE;
$result = $gender->get($name, $country);
$data = $gender->country($country);

switch($result) {
    case Gender::IS_FEMALE:
        printf("The name %s is female in %s\n", $name, $data['country']);
    break;
    case Gender::IS_MOSTLY_FEMALE:
        printf("The name %s is mostly female in %s\n", $name, $data['country']);
    break;
    case Gender::IS_MALE:
        printf("The name %s is male in %s\n", $name, $data['country']);
    break;
    case Gender::IS_MOSTLY_MALE:
        printf("The name %s is mostly male in %s\n", $name, $data['country']);
    break;
    case Gender::IS_UNISEX_NAME:
        printf("The name %s is unisex in %s\n", $name, $data['country']);
    break;
    case Gender::IS_A_COUPLE:
        printf("The name %s is both male and female in %s\n", $name, $data['country']);
    break;
    case Gender::NAME_NOT_FOUND:
        printf("The name %s was not found for %s\n", $name, $data['country']);
    break;
    case Gender::ERROR_IN_NAME:
        echo "There is an error in the given name!\n";
    break;
    default:
        echo "An error occurred!\n";
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without your CakePHP code I can only guess but yes, most likely the namespace creates the problem. CakePHP code has its own namespace and you cannot nest namespaces. Try this code instead:

```
$gender = new \Gender\Gender();
$name = "Milene";
$country = \Gender\Gender::FRANCE;

$result = $gender->get($name, $country);
$data = $gender->country($country);
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but I'm getting the error: Class 'Gender' not found. Note that this isn't code I've got in the Vendor or Plugin directory, it's a part of php and just enabled in php.ini. Its found here: http://pecl.php.net/package/gender

Comment: Hm, strange... Just a rough guess: have you checked that the Gender extension is enabled in the correct php.ini? E.g. on Ubuntu you have different php.ini files when running PHP from the commandline (/etc/php/(version)/cli/php.ini) and when running it as FPM (/etc/php/(version)/fpm/cli.php).

Comment: Yeah, the Gender extension works fine in a project that's not cakephp. So it's something to do with importing it into cakephp specifically. Thanks for taking an interest!

Comment: Do you run you "not cakephp" script from the CLI or via a web server?

Comment: via a web server

Comment: @PatrickGuinness The extension works fine with CakePHP, you're most certainly not using the correct code. The error message suggests that you are targeting the wrong namespace, ie you are using something like `new \Gender()`, otherwise it would say "_Class 'Gender\Gender' not found_" if you were targeting the correct namespace and the class couldn't be found.

Comment: @ndm - can you explain to me how to correctly use the extension in a controller function? I've tried all sorts but can't figure it out. Not very familiar with namespaces

Comment: @PatrickGuinness Exactly as shown in the above answer, the example works fine as is.

Comment: @ndm I'm using that exact code from the answer above but I'm still getting:Class 'Gender' not found. Is there somewhere other than the controller function where I'm meant to declare the extension or something? I just followed the instructions in the php manual but they're obviously not cake specific. Thanks

Comment: @PatrickGuinness Then the error maybe refers to a different place in your code, because as mentioned, if you were using `\Gender\Gender`, then you would get a different error message. Please show the error stacktrace (from the logs) and the code that the error is pointing to.

Comment: @ndm I've edited my question with the stack trace and code

Comment: @PatrickGuinness I suspect that the error points to the line with the first `case` statement? You are using `Gender` for targeting the constants, which must be `\Gender\Gender` unless you've [**imported the class**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php).